# Is there some open source tools for create tile map(IOS with cocos2d)?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, map-edit

I knew the tile-map java or QT version can create map by GUI tools. But what I asked is that I want to create map in my game. Just like the star-craft map editor in star-craft game, so do war3. Is there some useful map editor engine? If the tile-map can supply the tile-map editor engine(API) is great, and I would code the GUI by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tmx file is xml file + layer compressed with zlib and writen in base64.
Then you don't have binary version of the tmx file.

The lib compatible with the format is listed on:
https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Support-for-TMX-maps